# app_web .dll issue with null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am having an issue with testing my asp.NET website. lets say the form is defualt.aspx. When I try to open the form it gives me this weird error while trying to request a cookie value example:

```
     cookieVal = Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value;
```

The error message says:

```
    An exception of type 'System.Null.ReferenceException' occured in
    App_Web_default.aspx.dfa151d5.jahcut42.dll but was not handled in user code.
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue? I am very lost as I never had this error before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clearly stating that there is a `null` reference in the code, i.e, there is no such key called "cookie" in `Request.Cookies`. And if it is not there, then then `object` is `null` and you can't extract a `Value` property out of it. The correct way to handle this :

```
cookieVal = Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null ? Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value : null;
```

OR you can check if they `key` = "cookie" exists,

```
cookieVal = Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("cookie") ? Request.Cookies["cookie"].Value : null;
```